# How do i change the result of an ORACLE select query for specific type of data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named EMPLOYEES with columns EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME and DEPARTMENT_ID. I have to list all employees, changing the output of the attribute NAME to "---" if the department id is 10.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select 
    employee_id, 
    case when department_id = 10 then '---' else name end as name, 
    department_id
from employees;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `union all`

```
select 
    employee_id, name,  department_id
from employees WHERE department_id != 10
UNION all
select 
    employee_id, '---' name,  department_id
from employees WHERE department_id = 10
```